# How to use Epplus with cells containing few rows

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, epplus

I want to import some excel file using epplus
the problem is that some cells contains more than one row (and that cause a problem

My excel look like this (in realite their is more tests (test2,test3....)

[image]

I can only get the first column by this algorithm..but it will be more complicated to get the seconde column

```
 //this is the list than contain applications (column 2)
ICollection<Application> applications = new  List<Application>();
            int i = 0;

            for (int j = workSheet.Dimension.Start.Row;
                    j <= workSheet.Dimension.End.Row;
                    j=i+1)
            {
                 //this is the object that contain the first column
                //and also a list of the second column  (foreach domain thei `is a list of applications (column 2)`          
                Domaine domaine = new Domaine();

                i += 1;

                //add here and  not last row
                while (workSheet.Cells[i, 1].Text == "" && i < workSheet.Dimension.End.Row)
                {

                    i++;
                }

                if (i > workSheet.Dimension.End.Row)
                    break;
                domaine.NomDomaine = workSheet.Cells[i, 1].Text;
                domaines.Add(domaine);

            }
```

Edit : in other words  is their a way to get the number of rows in one cell , OR a way to duplicate  the value of each row in the cell

(for exemple if i have a cell from row 1 to 14  and the row number 5 have value)
how can i duplicate that text to all the rows (that will help me solving the problem)

Comment: Please ask a real/concrete question!
It feels like you will need two for loops to get all data. You are currently not using j at all and have 1 hardcode for the cells index.

Comment: accualy i wanted to add the image to explain well  but it's seems not getting updated ...  the j is for getting  the last row in the worksheet !

Comment: Just to confirm - For this problem you only care about READING the values spreadsheet, yes? You have no need to write values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those are known as Merged cells. Values from merged cells are stored in the `.Value` property of the *first* cell in the merged range. This means we need to do just a little bit more work in order to read the value from a merged cell using EPPlus.

EPPlus provides us with a couple of properties that help us get to the correct reference though. Firstly we can use a cell's `.Merge` property to find out if it is part of a merged range. Then we can use the the worksheet's `.MergedCells` property to find the relevant range. It's then just a matter of finding the first cell in that range and returning the value.

So, in summary:

1. Determine if the cell we need to read from is part of a merged range using `.Merge`
2. If so, get the index of the merged range using the worksheet's `.MergedCells` property
3. Read the value from the first cell in the merged range

Putting this together we can derive a little helper method to take a worksheet object and row/col indices in order to return the value:

```
static string GetCellValueFromPossiblyMergedCell(ExcelWorksheet wks, int row, int col)
{
    var cell = wks.Cells[row, col];
    if (cell.Merge)                                              //(1.)
    {
        var mergedId = wks.MergedCells[row, col];                //(2.)
        return wks.Cells[mergedId].First().Value.ToString();     //(3.)
    }
    else
    {
        return cell.Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

**Worked example**

If I have a domain class like this:

```
class ImportedRecord
{
    public string ChildName { get; set; }
    public string SubGroupName { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
}
```

that I wanted to read from a spreadsheet that looked like this:

[image: excel screenshot]

Then I could use this method:

```
static List<ImportedRecord> ImportRecords()
{
    var ret = new List<ImportedRecord>();
    var fInfo = new FileInfo(@"C:\temp\book1.xlsx");
    using (var excel = new ExcelPackage(fInfo))
    {
        var wks = excel.Workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
        var lastRow = wks.Dimension.End.Row;

        for (int i = 2; i <= lastRow; i++)
        {
            var importedRecord = new ImportedRecord
            {
                ChildName = wks.Cells[i, 4].Value.ToString(),
                SubGroupName = GetCellValueFromPossiblyMergedCell(wks,i,3),
                GroupName = GetCellValueFromPossiblyMergedCell(wks, i, 2)
            };
            ret.Add(importedRecord);
        }
    }

    return ret;
}

static string GetCellValueFromPossiblyMergedCell(ExcelWorksheet wks, int row, int col)
{
    var cell = wks.Cells[row, col];
    if (cell.Merge)
    {
        var mergedId = wks.MergedCells[row, col];
        return wks.Cells[mergedId].First().Value.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        return cell.Value.ToString();
    }
}
```