# I want to traverse Excel cells to get data with C#

Tags: c#, excel-2010

I want to traverse Excel cells to get data, but the cells is not regular. For example: the red cell which is  merged by multiple rows. how to traverse all rows?

[image]

I want to traverse rows to get data as follows:

1. 081701-b-aaaa-y;
2. 081702-c-aaaa-y;
3. 081704-d-aaaa-y;
4. 081703-e-ffff-k;
5. ...

Is there any good ways to achieve it?

Comment: To parse excel, there is already a good implementation within .NET framework. I haven't tried exactly about parsing the merged cells, but you can play around with it and see. Its in another post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282999/reading-csv-file-and-storing-values-into-an-array/33796861#33796861.
More details about the parser is given here: http://codeskaters.blogspot.ae/2015/11/c-easiest-csv-parser-built-in-net.html

Comment: @Habeeb, thank you very much! I'm sorry for replying to you so late! I can not open the link "codeskaters.blogspot.ae/2015/11/…", could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend EPPlus: http://epplus.codeplex.com/

```
var package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo("sample.xlsx"));

ExcelWorksheet workSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];

for (int i = workSheet.Dimension.Start.Column;
        i <= workSheet.Dimension.End.Column;
        i++)
{
    for (int j = workSheet.Dimension.Start.Row;
            j <= workSheet.Dimension.End.Row;
            j++)
    {
        object cellValue = GetCellValueFromPossiblyMergedCell(workSheet,i, j);
    }
}
```

In the case of merged cells, I believe you refer to a merged cell by its top left cell reference. The following helper method will get you the value of a merged cell.

```
static string GetCellValueFromPossiblyMergedCell(ExcelWorksheet wks, int row, int col)
    {
        var cell = wks.Cells[row, col];
        if (cell.Merge)                                              //(1.)
        {
            var mergedId = wks.MergedCells[row, col];                //(2.)
            return wks.Cells[mergedId].First().Value.ToString();     //(3.)
        }
        else
        {
            return cell.Value.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Helper method sourced from: [How to use Epplus with cells containing few rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36978100/how-to-use-epplus-with-cells-containing-few-rows)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm sorry for replying to you so late! The way can not resolve merged cells. For example:  get the second row data is : 081702-c-""-y;   workSheet.Cells[2, 3]  is "".

Comment: @Superman I've updated the example code to show how to pull the value out of a merged range.

Comment: Great！Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi Daniel, I have met a problem, Could you help me? Thank you very much!   sheet3.Cells["A1:B5"].Merge = true;
            var mergedId = sheet3.MergedCells[1, 1];
            sheet3.Cells[mergedId].First().Value = "123"; // error: System.InvalidOperationException : Sequence does not contain any elements    The link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42408861/set-cells-merged-and-set-its-value-but-it-not-work