# Set cells merged and set its value, but it not work？

Tags: c#, epplus

//use EPPlus.dll

using OfficeOpenXml

```
string path = @"C:\Users\Superman\Desktop\recc\1996.xlsx";
            ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(path));
            var sheet3 = package.Workbook.Worksheets[3];
            sheet3.Cells["A1:B5"].Merge = true;
            var mergedId = sheet3.MergedCells[1, 1];
            sheet3.Cells[mergedId].First().Value = "123"; // error: System.InvalidOperationException : Sequence does not contain any elements
            package.Save();
```

What's wrong? How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer why the exception from using the `First()` method - I would bet money that your `sheet3` in excel is empty.  Remember that the `Cells` object only contains references to cell that have **actual** content.  But if all of the cells in excel are empty then so is the `Cells` collection in EPPlus.

For example, this works fine when creating a brand new sheet:

```
using (var package = new ExcelPackage(fi))
{
    var brandNewSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("BrandNewSheet");
    brandNewSheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(new[] {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"});
    brandNewSheet.Cells["B1"].LoadFromCollection(new[] {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"});
    brandNewSheet.Cells["A1:B5"].Merge = true;
    var mergedId = brandNewSheet.MergedCells[1, 1];
    brandNewSheet.Cells[mergedId].First().Value = "123";
    package.Save();
}
```

But if you comment out the `LoadFromCollection` calls you will get the runtime exception:

```
using (var package = new ExcelPackage(fi))
{
    var brandNewSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("BrandNewSheet");
    //brandNewSheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(new[] {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"});
    //brandNewSheet.Cells["B1"].LoadFromCollection(new[] {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"});
    brandNewSheet.Cells["A1:B5"].Merge = true;
    var mergedId = brandNewSheet.MergedCells[1, 1];
    brandNewSheet.Cells[mergedId].First().Value = "123"; //Cells is empty so: System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements
    package.Save();
}
```

As others have explain, there is no need to call `First()` to get what you want but figured I was at least address that.

Comment: You are great! Thank you very much!

Comment: I have another problem, if  original sheet file Cells["A1:B1"] is merged, and is empty, but  sheet3.Cells["A1:B1"].Count() = 2? why not 0?

Comment: Could you help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: @Superman  Hum....that doesnt seem right.  Are you seeing this with the above code I posted?  Or is this on your own sheet?  `.Count()` is a LINQ expression so it should behave consistently with `.First()`.

Comment: if original sheet file Cells["A1:B1"] is merged, and is empty, var cell = sheet3.Cells["A1:B1"].First(); according to what you said that  the merged cells is empty, it should throw exception,  but it did not throw exception, it was executed successly, why?

Comment: @Superman I often see that when cells appear empty but actually contain whitespace somehow. But that is just a guess.  Hard to say specifically without looking at the sheet itself.  Maybe post it somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

just a suggestion: use "using"

and a small change in your code:

```
    using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(path)))
    {
        var sheet3 = package.Workbook.Worksheets[3];
        sheet3.Cells["A1:B5"].Merge = true;
        var mergedId = sheet3.MergedCells[1, 1];
        sheet3.Cells["A1"].Value = "123"; 
        package.Save();
    }
```

I think the range wasn't recognized anymore, because you have merged it

**EDIT1:**

this code works for me like a charm. I think you don't need `.First()`

```
using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(path)))
            {
                var sheet3 = package.Workbook.Worksheets[3];
                sheet3.Cells["A1:B5"].Merge = true;
                var mergedId = sheet3.MergedCells[1, 1];
                sheet3.Cells[mergedId].Value = "123";
                package.Save();
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But I can not understand why sheet3.Cells[mergedId].First().Value = "123"; has error? sheet3.Cells["A1:B5"].Merge = true; var mergedId = sheet3.MergedCells[1, 1]; // mergeId got correct value,  Why sheet3.Cells[mergedId].Count() = 0??

Comment: But to answer why it happens... have no idea. sorry

Answer (score 1):

If you comment out the line that generates the error, are the cells in the resulting sheet merged? If they are, try simply assigning a value to cell A1 and see if that works.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply! According to what you say, It works ! But I can not understand why sheet3.Cells[mergedId].First().Value = "123"; has error? mergedId got correct value.

Comment: Try taking First() out? Don't see what it's there for

Comment: sheet3.Cells[mergedId].First(): represent range's first cell, for examle range: A1:B1, then represent the cell：A1

Comment: Do you get an error if you take that out and just leave sheet3.cells[mergedId].Value = "123"?

Comment: original excel file range:mergedId is merged, so the code :sheet3.Cells[mergedId].First().Value = "123"; can be executed correctly. If original excel file range : mergedId is not merged,    then the code : sheet3.Cells["A1:B5"].Merge = true;
            var mergedId = sheet3.MergedCells[1, 1];
            sheet3.Cells[mergedId].First().Value = "123"; // error: System.InvalidOperationException : Sequence does not contain any elements

Comment: I'll try to replicate the problem in a few hours, if you don't solve it by then

Comment: just leave sheet3.cells[mergedId].Value = "123" can be executed correctly! But why sheet3.Cells[mergedId].First().Value = "123"; has error? Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't think that's the correct way to iterate through a merged cell's subcells. I'm not even sure EPPlus allows you to do that - plus, it is not needed here

Comment: But if original excel file range:mergeId is merged,  the code: sheet3.Cells[mergedId].First().Value = "123"; can be execute correctly

Comment: Can you post the code that you run on the already merged sheet? Is it exactly the same?

Comment: Yeah, The excel file sheet is already merged. The code is follow: ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(path));
            var sheet3 = package.Workbook.Worksheets[3];                                           var mergeId = sheet3.MergedCells[1, 1];
                sheet3.Cells[mergeId].First().Value = "123";                                                             package.Save();

Answer (score 1):

You already have an inline `ExcelRange` in your example code above:

```
sheet3.Cells["A1:B5"].Merge = true;
```

So save a *reference*, and use it to set the merged cell value:

```
using (var package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(path)))
{
    var sheet3 = package.Workbook.Worksheets[3];
    var range = sheet3.Cells["A1:B5"];
    range.Merge = true;
    sheet3.Cells[range.Start.Address].Value = "123";
    package.Save();
}
```

Now there's no need to calculate or hard-code cell addresses or indexes. In other words, when you did this:

```
var mergedId = sheet3.MergedCells[1, 1];
```

the code throws `System.InvalidOperationException` because `mergedId` is `A1:B5`.

Conversely:

```
range.Start.Address // A1
```

correctly sets the cell value.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But I can not understand why sheet3.Cells[mergedId].First().Value = "123"; has error?     Suppose, original excel file  range:mergedId  is merged, so the code :sheet3.Cells[mergedId].First().Value = "123";  can be executed correctly. If original excel file range : mergedId is not merged, then the code has error. what's wrong?